# shell script - while loop, handle the exception

Tags: scripting, shell-scripting, stty

I am running a shell script with a while loop and it exits with the below error, how could I avoid it or catch the error and let the loop to continue ? ie how could I handle the exception

```
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

Following are the script I am trying but it exit from the loop after the first iteration.

```
hfile=/tmp/prty.txt
while read property
do
 hostname=`echo $property | awk '{print $1}'`
 echo $hostname
 ssh -l gger $hostname ". <userhome>/.bash_profile; ggsci -v; exit  << EOF > /tmp/gg.txt

 EOF"
done < $hfile

file hfile
==========
user1  pas1
user2  pas2
user3  pas3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've had more caffeine I can see that the error message you are getting is a [red herring.](https://serverfault.com/posts/460215/revisions#rev16521274-35f7-4959-8c3b-7c20988c7171)

At the point that you execute ssh it is given control of stdin which it will fully consume. This means that it will read the data from `$hfile` which in turn means that after one iteration of the loop the while ends.

You can use the `-n` switch to  ssh to solve this problem.

```
ssh -n -l gger $hostname ". <us...
```

> -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from
>                stdin)...

Comment: @Arn: See my latest update